# JPA Entity as an object in a method which consumes application/json in Jax-RS

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

My application is to do some database actions using JPA based on the requests to a JaxRS service.

Following is the entity class I use for JPA.

```
import javax.annotation.Generated; 
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Student  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private int index;

@Column(length = 25)
private String name;

@Version
@Column(length = 45)
private Date timestamp;

public Student(int index, String name) {
    this.index = index;
    this.name = name;
}

public Student() {
}

public int getIndex() {
    return index;
}

public void setIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Following is the method in my JaxRS service

```
@POST
@Path("add")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response addStudent(Student student) {
    return null;
}
```

Please ignore the `return null;` for the moment.

In the POST request this needs to have a json object like the following,

```
'{"name":"Student 1", "index": 12, "id": "1", "timestamp" : "2014-07-21 12:19:12"}'
```

How can I make it possible just to have a json like,

```
'{"name":"Student 1", "index": 12}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem there - the parameter `student` is a new instance, the id is autogenerated, and you will need to set the current time in the versioned timestamp column by hand. Some implementations may even do the last one for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add JPA @EntityListeners that would set version property to current timestamp. A small trick is to force that your class implements some interface that would be recognized by EntityListener class: that way, all your classes that are versionable are automatically versioned on @PrePersist and @PreUpdate events:

```
public interface IVersionable {
    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp);
}

@Entity
@EntityListeners(MyEntityListener.class)
public class Student implements IVersionable  {
    // getters/setters omitted

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}

public class MyEntityListener {
    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void prePersistUpdate(final Object entity) {
        if (entity instanceof IVersionable) {
            ((IVersionable) entity).setTimestamp(new Date());
        }
    }  
}
```